# Is there a way to call setBackgroud() in an exented class of JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I'm setting up a simulation of Conway's game of life. I wanted to create a set of boxes that are of type 'Mybox' that extends 'JPanel'. Inside of each of these boxes I would like to call the function SetBackground() when the program starts. Here is the closest Ive came to getting it working

```
package conwaysGameOfLife;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Panel;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyBox extends JPanel{
    public void setBackground(Color color){
        super.setBackground(color);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }
}
```

When I enter this I receive errors telling me to make setBackground() static but when I do I get an error under the supper keyword.

Answer (score 0):

setBackground() should not be static. 
In your main(), you need to create an instance of MyBox and use that instance:

```
MyBox box = new MyBox();
box.setBackground( Color.red );
```

For example:

```
public class MyBox extends JPanel{

    public MyBox() {
         this( Color.GREEN );
    }

    public MyBox(Color color){
        setBackground(color);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create an instance with green background
        // using the default constructor:
        MyBox greenBox = new MyBox();

        // or use the other constructor 
        MyBox redBox = new MyBox(Color.RED);
        // then later you can change the color:
        redBox.setBackground(Color.white);
    }
}
```